# How do I fix my navbar text?

Tags: css, navbar

For my website (www.heretoedit.com) I want to move the text in my navbar so that the "about" button is lined up with the rest of my website's text but the "contact" button stays put. Plus I want to stop the text for the "extras" and "contact" buttons from moving down when the screen size gets reduced.

Below is my navbar code, any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

---

```
#navbar {
background-color: #0299EB;
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
color: white;   
font-weight: bold;
position: absolute;
width: 1000px;
min-width: 100%;
height: 70px;
top: 150px;
left: 0px;
} 

#navbar ul {
list-style:none;
display:inline-block;    
margin-left: 130px;
margin-top: 25px;
}

#navbar li {
float:left;
padding: 0 9px;
text-align:center;
left: 0px;
}

#navbar a:link {
padding: 0 30px;
text-decoration: none;
color: #FFF;
}

#navbar a:hover {
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
}

#navbar a:visited {
color: #FFF;
padding: 0 20px;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#navbar ul {

    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;

    /* Add these */
    margin: 25px 0px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;

}
#navbar li {

    /* float: left; // Remove this */
    padding: 0 9px;
    text-align: center;
    left: 0px;
    display: inline-block; /* Add this */

}
```